# Move semantics in C++11

Tags: c++, c++11, operators, move-semantics, move-constructor

I would like to fully understand move semantics in C++11. So I have written a couple of classes to see when different constructors are called:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class A {
public:
    A() : a1_(0) {std::cout << "Calling constructor" << std::endl;}
    A(A&& other) {
        std::cout << "Calling move constructor" << std::endl;
        a1_ = other.a1_;
        other.a1_ = 0;
    }

    // Move assignment operator.
    A& operator=(A&& other) {
        std::cout << "Calling move operator" << std::endl;
        if (this != &other) {
            a1_ = other.a1_;
            other.a1_ = 0;
        }
        return *this;
    }

    // Copy constructor.
    A(const A& other) {
        std::cout << "Calling copy constructor" << std::endl;
        a1_ = other.a1_;
    }

    // Copy assignment operator.
    A& operator=(const A& other) {
        std::cout << "Calling copy assignment operator" << std::endl;
        if (this != &other) {
            a1_ = other.a1_;
        }
        return *this;
    }

private:
    int a1_;
};

class B {
    A oA_;

public:
    B() {}
    void setoA(A a) {oA_ = a;}
        A getoA() {return oA_;}
};

A createA() {
    A a1;
    return a1;
}

B createB() {
    B tmpB;
    A tmpA;
    tmpB.setoA(tmpA);
    return tmpB;
}

int main() {
    B b;
    A a;
    b.setoA(a);
    std::cout << "**************************" << std::endl;
    b.setoA(createA());
    std::cout << "**************************" << std::endl;
    b.setoA(std::move(createA()));
    std::cout << "**************************" << std::endl;
    B b2;
    b2.setoA(b.getoA());
    std::cout << "**************************" << std::endl;
    createB();

    return 0;
}
```

When I check the output of this code:

```
    Calling constructor

    Calling constructor

    Calling copy constructor

    Calling copy assignment operator

    ++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++

    Calling constructor

    Calling copy assignment operator

    ++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++

    Calling constructor

    Calling move constructor

    Calling copy assignment operator

    ++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++

    Calling constructor

    Calling copy constructor

    Calling copy assignment operator

    ++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++

    Calling constructor

    Calling constructor

    Calling copy constructor

    Calling copy assignment operator
```

I have some doubts here:

I thought that if you pass `r-value`, move constructor will be called, is that right? Isn't this `b.setoA(createA());` an `r-value`?

How can I make move constructor/operator being called?

Comment: The output didn't come from your snippet, please fix it.

Comment: Yes it did, I only replaced **** string by +++++

Comment: `a` and `b`'s `A` are being constructed in the first segment. How many construction calls do you expect?

Comment: `void setToA(A a)` passes a by copy. Therefore a temporary object of type A is created when entering `b.setToA(a)`.

Comment: If your question(s) about the first section please remove irrelevant code and output, ie create [mcve]

Comment: Copy elision is a thing.

Comment: You have too much cargo in your classes. Remove the irrelevant code. Irrelevant in respect to move semantics.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> First of all in first section, why is constructor being called twice?

Because you construct both an `B` and a `A` with the former having its own instance of `A`, which the first (the unexpected) constructor call comes from.

> I thought that if you pass r-value move constructor will be called, is that right? Isn't this `b.setoA(createA());` an r-value?

The constructor is called from within `createA` (and yes, return value *is* an r-value), however, copy elision occurs and the object is directly instantiated in the parameter variable of `setoA`.

Within `setoA`, however, the copy assignment is selected, as now `a` is an l-value. If you want to move, you need:

```
void setoA(A a) { oA_ = std::move(a); }
```

Answer (score 0):

Some copies and moves may be optionally elided by the compiler. To prevent this, use `-fno-elide-constructors` in GCC and Clang. In addition, some move elisions became mandatory in C++17, so to force the compiler to use C++11 move semantics, use `-std=c++11` as well.